# RSpec params are all string, breaking tests

Tags: rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing some controller/request specs, and currently working on an update request. Fairly straight forward, and in a number of other cases this is working perfectly, however I seem to have hit a snag.

In my routes.rb file, I have limited the actions of a controller as so

```
resources :model, except: [:destroy, :edit, :new]
```

To avoid the issue of having the `show` action called if a user requested `/new`, I added a constraint, so the route now looks like

```
resources :model, except: [:destroy, :edit, :new], constraints: { id: /\d/ }
```

This works nicely, and requesting `/new` results in a 404, however I'm now having a problem with my request test, as RSpec seems to make all of the parameters strings.

In my test, I am doing

```
resource = FactoryGirl.create(:model)
params = { id: resource.id, resource: { edited: true }}
put :update, params
```

However this is resulting in the error

```
No route matches {:id=>"10", :resource=>{:edited=>true}, :controller=>"models", :action=>"update"}
```

If this error is right, then it seems that despite me setting the id param to be the integer ID stored in the resource (even when I put .to_i on it explicitly) the param is being sent through as a string, and not matching a route because of my constraint.

Is there a way of stopping this behaviour? My routing tests are working as expected, so I'm confused as to why this is failing.

**UPDATE**

Interestingly, if I move the tests from being controller specs to request specs, this no longer fails and is working correctly. I'm happy to make them all request specs but I'm still curious as to why this is happening or whether I've stumbled onto a bug in rSpec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex specifies a single digit `id`, but you're passing in a two digit id. Perhaps a fix is as simple as changing the regex to `/\d+/`.